# Is there an idiom for adding a database query to a Qt model?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, model-view-controller

I have a Qt QAbstractItemModel, and the underlying information is inside an sqlite database.  I want to incrementally add rows from a database query to the model as they are needed.  The database fetch may be slow, however.  My problem is that beginInsertRows() needs to be called before the model is modified, but it needs to know how many rows will be added.  I won't know that until after I do the query.  This means I seem to have the following alternatives, all of which are unattractive.

1. Do two database queries:  "SELECT COUNT(*) …" to get the number of result rows, then call beginInsertRows(), and do the real query.  The downside, of course, is that a potentially expensive query has to be done twice.
2. Do my entire query, buffer the results, count the rows, then call beginInsertRows() and insert them into the model.  The downside is all the extra buffering.
3. Call beginInsertRows()/endInsertRows() once for each row in the result set.  This is going to cause a whole bunch of unnecessary view updates.

This seems like a general problem to me.  Is there a general solution?  For instance, is there a way to tell beginInsertRows() one thing and then change your mind?

Thanks.

Comment: The correct way is to implement `QAbstractItemModel::canFetchMore` and `QAbstractItemModel::fetchMore`. Also did you try to use built-in `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSqlTableModel` classes? They already implement this behavior.

Comment: I'm doing that, but it seems that the tree view only calls canFetchMore/fetchMore twice when an index is expanded.  What I see is that if each fetch returns N rows, my view displays 2N rows the first time an index is expanded, even if there are other rows in the result set - canFetchMore isn't even checked again.  That leads me back to having to fetch all of the rows when an index is first expanded, so I'm back to the same problem.  Is there some trick to do this?

Comment: I haven't tried the built-in SQL classes because I'm working with an in-house library that needs to be used by non-Qt applications as well, so I'm going through a slightly higher-level interface than raw sqlite.